# Java module system: how to avoid leaking all packages of transitive modules

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

In java module system, we can have:

```
module hellomodule {
    exports com.name.hello;
    requires transitive greetings;
}
```

by doing this the packages exposed by `greetings` module will effectively become part of the API exposed by the `hellomodue`.

We may want to avoid this to a certain degree, would be nice, for example, to allow only visibility on certain classes,  the ones used by `hellomodule` in the signature of the methods it contains perhaps.

Is there any way to do this, i.e. allow only certain classes or packages to be leaked ?

Comment: No. All classes of `greetings` will be exposed. If you want to not expose some of them, divide them into different modules, like `greetings-api` and `greetings-impl` module.

Comment: Yes, indeed but what about third party dependencies ? we may end up with a client module using the API `greetings`, that we did not intend to leak, making so refactoring a bit more difficult.

Comment: @GionJh: if a third party made a module it's not up to you to sub-divide that module further. Expose all or nothing. What if yet another module on the module path depends on the whole module?

Comment: Yes agred, was just thinking that this, deciding what to expose, would be a nice feature, if other modues need the whole module they would require it explicitely.